# How to select row if every row have given value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table , which have following row.

Now I'm executing below query.

```
select IdeaId,Count(IdeaId) as Total from testTable 
where IdeaId in (100,2,3) 
group by IdeaId,Status
having Status = 'Submitted'
```

I gave me result .

```
IdeaId  Total
100     1
2       1
3       1
```

> But I want, When I Pass Idead ids in `IN` query, Then It should return
>   only those IdeadId which have all row have status submitted, If any
>   row corresponding to IdeaId have status other than submitted, Then
>   that ideadId should not return.

I am using MS SQL server 2014

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry: I know how to post question. I have added what I have tried. But I'm not getting what I want .

Comment: Do you need count ideadId's , which only  have  'Submitted' status?

Comment: @OtoShavadze: No . If all idead Id have status `Submitted` then It should return otherwise no. Like from above table 100 & 2 should not return because these 2 have status other that Submitted. If all row have status Submitted then only return

Comment: @AmitKumar you can check now my ans

Comment: You most assuredly do not

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need to use case statement for your result.

I am consider are you using mysql

```
select IdeaId,Count(IdeaId) as Total
from testTable 
where IdeaId NOT IN(select IdeaId from testTable where Status!='Submitted')
and IdeaId IN(100,2,3)
group by IdeaId,Status
```

Comment: No it won't give correct result. Your query will include ideadId 100. But my requirement it IdeaId 100 should not be in result as it has status `NULL` and `Pending`

Comment: @AmitKumar check now

Comment: Thank it's working . I have a query. Shouldn't I use In query in nested select statement. like this `IdeaId NOt int  (select IdeaId from testTable where Status!='Submitted' and IdeaId IN(100,2,3))`

Comment: How will you know which status corresponds with which count? (Hint: You won't)

Comment: The solution will not exluce cases where `status is null`, therefore the -1 is justified.

Comment: @cars10 he need to count only which has submitted even he do not need 100 id because it has null and pending. you can see i have used !=

Comment: @Strawberry you can see my above comment

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want the `status`-condition included in your `where`-clause, not the `having` clause:

```
select IdeaId,Count(IdeaId) as Total from testTable 
where IdeaId in (100,2,3) AND Status = 'Submitted'
group by IdeaId
```

**Edit**:
The following query returns, what the OP *really* wants: all rows where the `IdeaId` appears *only* with Status "Submitted" and nothing else:

```
select IdeaId, COUNT(*) Total from testTable WHERE IdeaId in (100,2,3) AND
  IdeaId NOT IN (
    SELECT IdeaId FROM testTable
    WHERE IdeaId in (100,2,3) AND COALESCE(Status,'null') != 'Submitted'
)
```

In this case only `IdeaId`=2 fulfills this criterion.
    group by IdeaId

Comment: No it won't give correct result. Your query will include ideadId 100. But my requirement it IdeaId 100 should not be in result as it has status `NULL` and `Pending`

Comment: Ahh, OK, that clarified the point I was *not* clear about ... Now everybody can join in again to find the right solution!

Comment: Does it necessary to put `IdeaId in (100,2,3)` in first line where condition.

Comment: It *is* necessary, since my negative subquery excludes the cases you don't want, but the main query still has to limit it on the cases where `IdesId` is in your desired set. You *could* leave the condition out in the subquery, as @knowledge has done in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select IdeaId, count(*) as cnt  
from testTable 
where IdeaId in( 2,3,100)
group by IdeaId 
having count(*) = count(case when Status =  'Submitted' then 1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
select IdeaId,Count(IdeaId) as Total from 
( select distinct IdeaId from testTable  
  where Status = 'Submitted' 
  minus 
  select distinct  IdeaId from testTable  
  where Status <> 'Submitted') resultTable
  where IdeaId ( 100,2,3)
  group by IdeaId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`select IdeaId,
Count(IdeaId) as Total 
from testTable 
where IdeaId in (100,2,3) 
AND Status = 'Submitted' 
and IdeaId not in (select IdeaId from testtable 
                   where Status<> 'Submitted' 
                   or status is  null )
group by IdeaId`
```

I guess this will give your desired output :)